How to motivate that in presence of gravity the spacetime metric must be modified to $ds^2=g_{ab}(x)dx^adx^b$?
In the presence of a gravitational field, the spacetime metric, $$ds^2=\eta_{ab}dx^a dx^b,$$ should be changed to, $$ds^2=g_{ab}(x)dx^adx^b.$$ What are the convincing physical arguments that motivate this point?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity

This is a standard definition in geometry. There is nothing to motivate. The whole point is that in GR, spacetime isn't necessarily flat. So $g$ is no longer necessarily equal to $\eta$.

"The whole point is that in GR, spacetime isn't necessarily flat." Do you take that as a postulate out of the blue?

@VincentThacker, using a postulated theory without the physical justifications that gave a physical sense of the theory is bad physics, in my opinion.  General Relativity was founded on simple ideas and principles (the equivalence principle, that started the whole theory).  These ideas may become "useless" after the whole theory have been formulated, but we still need its physical justifications to motivate its formulation.

The world is divided into bananas and non-bananas. Most things are non-bananas. That's not a postulate, it is just an obvious fact. Functions can be divided into constants and non-constants. Many interesting functions are not constant, that is not a postulate, it is just a fact. $\eta$ is constant. $g$ is not constant.

Textbook reference: https://www.amazon.com/Gravitation-Cosmology-Principles-Applications-Relativity/dp/0471925675

@Solidification Yes. The premise of GR is that spacetime is described by a 4-dimensional manifold. And the most obvious justification of that is geodesic deviation, which implies a nonzero Riemann curvature.

@Cham I agree. But I originally interpreted the question as asking why the expression of the interval takes the form it takes, rather than why spacetime is described by a manifold.

@VincentThacker, well, that's the whole point of the question and you missed it!  At first, before we get a full mathematical General Relativity (with the notion of curved manifold), we had the Minkowski spacetime and its flat metric.  Then we want to add gravity.  We don't have a choice but to generalize the metric to get curvature (and then the curved manifold).  This is the physics way, not the mathematician way.  The mathematical route (from all the mathematical machinery) is not the right physics way, in my opinion.  It's just the mathematician path which don't know much about physics!

It's a consequence of the equivalence principle, for which a gravitational field is locally indiscernible from an acceleration effect, for any moving small body.  And the corollary: a free fall in a gravitational field is locally indiscernible from an inertial motion in Minkowski spacetime.  Since the observer could have any motion and may use any coordinates system, the Minkowski metric should be promoted to a general spacetime metric.
This is so simple and beautiful that I have a very hard time in thinking how this could be false!  Unless we discover one day that different particles could have different accelerations in a given gravitational field.

"Since the observer could have any motion and may use any coordinates system, the Minkowski metric should be promoted to a general spacetime metric." But the observer can use any coordinate system in in flat spacetime.

@Solidification, the Minkowski metric may be formulated for any coordinates system and any observer motion, yes, but it's still the Minkowski metric: flat geometry (without curvature) and without any real gravitational field.  The equivalence principle is a local principle only.  So to add a gravitational field, we need to use 1) a scalar field in Minkowski spacetime (aka Nordstrom theory or its variants), or 2) use a more general metric (with curvature) that extends the Minkowski metric.  It appears that the simple scalar theory is too simple and doesn't fit with observations.
